# An upper bound $u$ is the supremum of $A$ if and only if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $a \in A$ such that $u-\epsilon < a$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

**Problem**:

Let $u$ be an upper bound of non-empty set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
Prove that $u$ is the supremum of $A$
if and only if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $a \in A$ such that
$u-\epsilon < a$.

**Solution**:

(i) $\implies$ (ii) Suppose $u$ is the supremum of $A$, then this is obvious. Suppose this were not true. Then, $\forall a \in A$ and $\forall \epsilon > 0$, we have $u - \epsilon > a$. This contradicts the fact that $u$ is the least upper bound, as we could take $m = u - \epsilon$ to be a smaller upper bound for each $\epsilon$. \
(ii) $\implies$ (i) Suppose there exists a $u$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists a \in A$ such that $u - \epsilon < a$.  If this is satisfied, I claim that $u \geq a$ for each $a \in A$, and is the smallest such $u$, and thus $u = \sup A$. This follows directly from the definition of the supremum. Namely, take $a \in A$ and write $x=\sup A$. We may choose $\epsilon > 0$ such that $x-\epsilon < a$. We have two cases. If $a \in B_{\epsilon} (x)$, then $x-\epsilon < a$, where $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is the open ball around $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$. If $a \notin B_{\epsilon} (x)$, we may choose $n>1$ such that $a \in B_{n\epsilon}(x)$, implying $x-n\epsilon < a$. Thus we have shown that, for a supremum $x$, we may find $\epsilon > 0$ for each $a \in A$ such that $x-\epsilon < a$, which is equivalent to finding $a \in A$ for all $\epsilon > 0$. Ergo, $u$ is the supremum of $A$.

Is this a correct proof?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Answer (score 1):

You try to prove the first part via contradiction, however the proper negation of the sentence should be 'there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $u-\epsilon \ge a$ for all $a$.', not 'for all $\epsilon$, $u-\epsilon \ge a$'. You have the right idea for the rest of that part though.

For the second part you write:

> Suppose there exists a $u$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists a \in A$ such that $u - \epsilon < a$.  If this is satisfied, I claim that $u \geq a$ for each $a \in A$, and thus $u = \sup A$.

This isn't quite correct, you still need the assumption $u$ is an upper bound of $A$ (otherwise take $u=0.5$, $A=[0,1]$). Even if you did make this assumption the rest of your argument isn't quite satisfactory. You seem to say:

- Let $x$ be the supremum and $a\in A$, then you can choose $\epsilon$ such that $x-\epsilon < a$. That's fine, though maybe call $x$ $u$ for clarity.
- You say you have two cases, but you have chosen $\epsilon$ such that $a\in B_{\epsilon}(x)$, so only the first case applies.
- You conclude, but have not completed the proof. Namely you have shown 'for all $a$ there exists $\epsilon$', which is different to the goal which is 'for all $\epsilon$ there is an $a$'.

Thus the second part of your proof is incorrect.

Comment: I have updated my answer to talk about your second part, which I don't believe is correct.

Comment: Why is it not true that for each $\epsilon$ there is an $a$ is equivalent to for each $a$ there is an $\epsilon$? Obviously if there is an $\epsilon$ for each $a$, then there is an $a$ for each $\epsilon$?

Comment: Surely if I can choose an $\epsilon$ depending on my $a$, then given that $a$, I can choose the same $\epsilon$?

Comment: As for the cases, I'm saying that if $a$ is in this neighborhood, clearly our $\epsilon$ satisfies $x-\epsilon < a$ if $a$ is an element not in this neighborhood, we may find a bigger neighborhood to satisfy this.

Comment: Putting aside the proof, let's look at this statement 'Why is it not true that for each $\epsilon$ there is an $a$ is equivalent to for each $a$ there is an $\epsilon$'. Suppose there is some $a_0$ that works for all $\epsilon$, but no other $a$ works for any $\epsilon$. Then for any $\epsilon$ you can find an element of $A$ namely $a_0$, but given an arbitrary element of $A$ you are not guaranteed an $\epsilon$.

Comment: An English equivalent would be let 'for every person we can find a man + woman pair who created them', but that doesn't mean 'for every man +woman pair we can find a child they created'.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew pointed out, there are some errors in your proof, specially in the second part. Here is a slightly different approach.

Let $u$ be an upper bound of $A$.

$(i)\Rightarrow (ii)$. $\forall \epsilon >0$, we have $u-\epsilon<u$. Since $u$ is the **least** upper bound, $u-\epsilon$ can not be an upper bound, and thus $\exists a\in A$ such that $u-\epsilon < a$.

$(i)\Leftarrow (ii)$. You have to show that $u$ is the **least** upper bound. To see this, take any upper bound $v$ and show that $u\leq v$. Indeed, $\forall \epsilon>0$, we can find $a\in A$ such that $u-\epsilon < a \leq v$. In particular $u-\epsilon < v$. Since this is true $\forall \epsilon > 0$, it must be $u\leq v$.

Comment: Your logic in the last step for proving $(i) \Leftarrow (ii)$ is incorrect. $u-\epsilon < v$ does not imply $u\leq v$. If that were true, then from our problem statement, $u$ would have to be $\leq a$ for some $a\in A$. But we know that the supremum of a set is not at all forced to be less than or equal an element in the set.

Comment: I did not just say " $u-\epsilon < v \Rightarrow u \leq v$ ". As you mention, that statement is false. However, if the inequality holds for any $\epsilon > 0$, then it must be true that $u \leq v$.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Regarding your counterexample, we can not conclude $u\leq a$ for some $a\in A$. We can not do that because we do not have an element $a \in A$ such that $u-\epsilon < a$ **for any $\epsilon$**. We have something slightly different: For each $\epsilon$, we can find $a\in A$ such that $u-\epsilon < a$, but this element $a\in A$ may only work for that $\epsilon$ fixed in advance, not for any $\epsilon > 0$.